# How to use special characters for filtering results using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string searchField, string searchString,
                                   bool searchEmpty) where T : class
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    if (searchField == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("searchField");

    if (searchString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("searchString");

    return from item in source.AsParallel()
           let property = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(_ =>
               {
                   var searchFieldAttribute =
                       _.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (SearchFieldAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as
                       SearchFieldAttribute;

                   return searchFieldAttribute != null && Attribute.IsDefined(_, typeof (SearchFieldAttribute)) &&
                          searchFieldAttribute.Name == searchField;
               }).Single()
           let value = property.GetValue(item, null)
           let asString = value == null ? String.Empty : value.ToString()
           where
               searchEmpty && String.IsNullOrEmpty(asString) ||
               !searchEmpty && asString.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
           select item;
}
```

As you can see, I need to pass `searchString` parameter to this method and use it for searching or filtering `source` collection by checking whether string representation of property value contains `searchString`.
What should I improve in this method to use special characters (such as `*`, `%`, etc), which commonly used in search queries and `LIKE` statements in SQL. Is there any best practices, extensions or other implementations of `Contains()` method? Any advices and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `String` has `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` methods, along with `Contains` that correspond to leading wildcard, trailing wildcard, and both, respectively. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching attempts I've found solution from VB.NET language.
There is `Operators.LikeString` method that allows us to do wildcard matching, so the `where` clause should be rewritten as follows:

```
where
    searchEmpty && String.IsNullOrEmpty(asString) ||
    !searchEmpty && Operators.LikeString(asString.ToLower(), searchString.ToLower(), CompareMethod.Text)
```

And users will have possibilities to use special characters in their queries. Thanks for your attention.

**NB.** `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` should be referenced.